# Get value from database in client side

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Lnk_Edit" ToolTip="Edit Message" 
                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("MsgID") %>' 
                CommandName="Edit" 
                runat="server">
   <img id="Img2" src="Styles/Images/Edit.jpg" 
                  runat="server" 
                  style="border-style: none" alt="Edit Message" />
</asp:LinkButton>

<asp:PopupControlExtender 
        ID="CreateUser_PopupControlExtender" 
        runat="server" DynamicServicePath=""
        Enabled="True" 
        ExtenderControlID="" 
        TargetControlID="editmsg" 
        PopupControlID="Paneledit">
</asp:PopupControlExtender>
```

I have a edit button in the grid view, I pop up a panel containing text box. I want to fill those text box with the value selected by the user. I get Msg ID from the user click, How can I fill data from database in client side

Answer (score 0):

I have almost never used the ajax control extenders, but from what it looks you'll have to fill your Paneledit values after Lnk_Edit OnCommand (EDIT: ah! and CommandName == "Edit") event is fired.